# How to integrate inline-annotated tags into standoff annotation?

Tags: python, annotations, gate

I am doing some custom annotation on the [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) platform. Let’s say I have a sentence to tag below.

### Raw text

> the **McDonald's** is '**麦当劳**' in Chinese. so "I want some **McDonald's**" is "**我想吃麦当劳**" in Chinese.

Using GATE, I tagged 4 specific tokens (**McDonald’s** and **麦当劳**) of the above sentence with an “Entity” tag. GATE would automatically generate an XML standoff annotation file based on character location like below.

```
<TextWithNodes>the <Node id="4"/>McDonald's<Node id="14"/> is '<Node id="19"/>麦当劳<Node id="22"/>'in Chinese. so "I want some <Node id="51"/>McDonald's<Node id="61"/>" is "我想吃<Node id="70"/>麦当劳<Node id="73"/>" in Chinese.</TextWithNodes>
<!-- The default annotation set -->

<AnnotationSet>
<Annotation Id="0" Type="Entity" StartNode="19" EndNode="22">
</Annotation>
<Annotation Id="1" Type="Entity" StartNode="4" EndNode="14">
</Annotation>
<Annotation Id="2" Type="Entity" StartNode="70" EndNode="73">
</Annotation>
<Annotation Id="3" Type="Entity" StartNode="51" EndNode="61">
</Annotation>
</AnnotationSet>

</GateDocument>
```

### inline POS tagging

Next, I want to POS tag for the raw text on Python. The raw text as a input, the tagger would return tagged sentence like below.

> The/DT McDonald's/NN is/BE '麦当劳'/NN in/PP Chinese/NN ./PW

The problem is that I want to add this POS-tagging result to the GATE standoff annotation file, which includes each POS tag marked with start offset and end offset. For example,

```
<Annotation Id="4" POS="DT" StartNode="0" EndNode="2">
<Annotation Id="5" POS="NN" StartNode="4" EndNode="14">
…
</Annotation>
```

The reason why I rather stick to standoff annotation than inline annotation is that I still want to use GATE for the convenience of inter-annotation task (manually tagging “Entity” tag), but unfortunately Chinese POS tagger cannot be implemented on GATE. And it is undesirable to do POS tag first and do the manual annotation on GATE later, because different POS taggers would give different POS tag results and this could mess up the offsets of the raw text.
**Please anybody give some hints how to integrate inline POS tagging results into the XML standoff annotation, or useful tools for modifying character location-based standoff annotation on Python.**

Comment: Have a look at the **TaggerFramework** GATE plugin:  http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:parsers:taggerframework . It may be possible to wrap your tagger for GATE using this plugin.

Comment: Also **Chinese Plugin** may provide some help: http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:misc-creole:language-plugins:chinese